# div:contains not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm following [this example](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and typed `$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );` , but got an exception:

VM23376:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': 'div:contains('John')' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Post the code of yours

Comment: If you have any elements inside <div>, then change the selector as such. Say if you have <p> tags inside <div> then change your selector to
$( "div p:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );

Comment: @Gayathri: that *shouldn't* make a difference (except for being potentially a little more work), since the ancestor `<div>` will still contain the required string.

Comment: @gyre The error if jQuery is not loaded is `"'$' is undefined"`, OP's appears to be different

Comment: jQuery is loaded. It is a jQuery parser error

Comment: it works for me as expected in the website there is no error

Answer (score 1):

function '$' is unknow. You probably trying to execute this code in place where jQuery library wasn't loaded.

```js
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
John
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it works for me as expected without an error as you can see the screenshot.

you can run this link also [click on this link to see example](https://jsfiddle.net/muneerkhan555/zdn0L4h8/384/)

```
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>contains demo</title>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">. 
         </script>
        </head>
  <body>
    <div>John Resig</div>
    <div>George Martin</div>
    <div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
    <div>J. Ohn</div>
    <script>
      $("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", 
         "underline");</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**
Manually filter elements by text instead:

```js
$('div').filter(function(element){
    return $(element).text().includes('John')
}).css('text-decoration', 'underline' )
```

Comment: How does this answers _'div:contains('John')' is not a valid selector_? ... until OP's code is available there is no way telling what's wrong, and any answer until then will be a lucky guess and we don't do guessing here at SO, unless you post it as a comment

Comment: Hmmm, why go through all the trouble using filter when there is nothing wrong using the given selector??

Comment: I updated answer to state that this is a "try this instead" answer

Comment: What I am trying to say is that what's wrong here is the part we don't see, hence no answers what so ever can be anything but a lucky guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS vanilla to do this :

```js
function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return Array.from(elements).filter(function(element) {
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}

// Run Code
let found = contains('span', 'Find');
// You can also search with regex
found = contains('span', 'Find\\s*[A-Za-z]+');

for (let i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
  let elem = found[i];
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<p>Some text where you have span tag that said <span>Find Me</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was a copy-paste issue.
OP typed `'div:contains('John')'` instead of `"div:contains('John')"`.
Properly copy-pasted code works without any problem.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contains demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
 
<script>
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure? Looks identical to me. What does properly copy-pasted code even mean? How do you mess up a copy-paste?

Comment: @user83039 This snipped of code was taken from the jQuery website. Properly copy-pasted it works as you can see. You can mess up copy-paste in many different ways. My guess is that OP was using ` instead of ' or ". It is a common mistake for JS/HTML beginners

Answer (score -5):

You can store that string in a variable and call that variable in contains. Please have a look at this. Hope this will help you.

```
var name = "John";
$( "div:contains(name)" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

Comment: The way you've used `name` here will be read as a string, not a variable. This will try to select `div:contains(name)`, not `div:contains(John)`.